# Is there a property or API that changes UIView's coordinate system?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make a line chart object.

so, I searching various ways to change the UIView's coordinate system from left-up to left-down.

First of all, I'd like to know if there is a function, method or property surppored by apple's API.

Is there like this?

[image]

Comment: This technique is most commonly known as "subtraction from 480"...

Comment: The `transform` property of an `UIView` should be handy here. (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4)

Comment: convertY = 480 - ypoint <- you say this way?

Comment: @user1182731 yep. Or rather subtract from `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` to support all screen sizes.